# Sencha Touch Ext.List does not fill with the data of store

Tags: sencha-touch

Ext.List does not fill with the data of store, only shows two lines of empty list item. When I debug with firebug, I saw store is filled with the information in json data but list items does not shown.

Store object

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.ListStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
autoLoad: true,

config:
{
    model: 'MyApp.model.NewsData',
    fields: [{ name: 'haberId', mapping: 'haberId' },
            { name: 'haberGonderen', mapping: 'haberGonderen' },
            { name: 'haberDetay', mapping: 'haberDetay' },
            { name: 'haberZaman', mapping: 'haberZaman'}]
},

proxy: {
    id: 'ListStore',
    access: 'public'
}});
```

News object

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.NewsData', {
extend: "Ext.data.Model",
config: {
    fields: [
        'haberId',
        'haberGonderen',
        'haberDetay',
        'haberZaman'
    ]


}});
```

List View

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ListTemplate', {
extend: 'Ext.List',
title: 'Haber Listesi',
store : 'ListStore',
fullscreen: true,
itemTpl : '{haberGonderen}'});
```

Anybody has any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. May be this helps you.

**Store.js**

```
        Ext.define('MyApp.store.ListStore', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
        config:
        {   
            autoLoad: true,
            model: 'MyApp.model.NewsData',
            proxy: {
            id: 'ListStore',
            access: 'public'
            },
            fields: [{ name: 'haberId', mapping: 'haberId' },
                    { name: 'haberGonderen', mapping: 'haberGonderen' },
                    { name: 'haberDetay', mapping: 'haberDetay' },
                    { name: 'haberZaman', mapping: 'haberZaman'}]
        }

        });
```

**ListTemplate.js**

```
        Ext.define('MyApp.view.ListTemplate', {
        extend: 'Ext.List',
        config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        title: 'Haber Listesi',
        store : 'ListStore',
        itemTpl : '{haberGonderen}'
        }

        });
```